# "Visible" is true, but it not working

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
string result = BackUp.BackupDatabase(folder, fileName);
if (result == "Complete")
{
    BackupSuccessfullyLbl.Text = "BackUp created successfully.";
    BackupSuccessfullyPnl.Visible = true;
    if (BackUpPlaceRBL.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(folder + fileName);
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

By default "Visible" of "`BackupSuccessfullyPnl`" is false.

I have created a back-up from my db, then I have showed the successfull message.

I want to download the created file, `if BackUpPlaceRBL.SelectedIndex == 1.`

When `BackUpPlaceRBL.SelectedIndex != 1`, the "`BackupSuccessfullyPnl`" is shown perfectly. But when file is downloaded, panel is not visible. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransmitFile` take full control of  the response.

so although you set True to visibility of the control , the output response is actually a file which is downloaded. that's why you dont see the changes.

> So what can I do?

great.

you create an iframe which hosts a page which has this code of downloading a file(only).

and on your main screen(page) you can set the visible=true.